# How to mock requests.post(XXXXXX).json()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying and struggling to mock the HTTP request.

Please advise me how to mock the requests using json() method.

Mock code(Test)

```
class TestHandle(TestCase):
    response_json = {
        'id': 'UJ1jmz-0t6CADWtTuR4DOqfOuDzxCV0m',
    }

    # @patch('botocore.vendored.requests.post')
    @patch('botocore.vendored.requests.post', return_value=response_json)
    def test_handle(self, post_mock1):
        event = {"body": "{\"id\": \"user000001\",\"password\": \"pw000001\"}"}
        handle(event, context)
        self.assertEqual(post_mock1.call_count, 1)
```

Mocked code

```
response_json = requests.post('https://aaaa.sample/test', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
```

Result

```
Ran 2 tests in 5.463s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TempUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\TempUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\TempUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "C:\Users\TempUser\PycharmProjects\sample\functions\login\test\test_handle.py", line 27, in test_handle
    handle(event, context)
  File "C:\Users\TempUser\PycharmProjects\sample\functions\login\main.py", line 33, in handle
    response_json = requests.post('https://aaaa.sample/test', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'json'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I would like to do is just extract body(json format) from HTTP response.

Comment: What is your payload object?

Comment: payload is like this.

`payload = {'username': url_encode(id), 'password': password}`

Comment: have you found a way to do this